# how i can make my player stops the vibration from left to right?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

hello am using this code to make the player sprite follow the position of mouse (left /right) , but when the mouse stops in specific location the player follow it then began vibrating from left to right
i think the problem is in self.vel_x of the update function.

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
#init Player Sprite

#sprite player
def __init__(self):

    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    self.image=pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_folder,"Player.png"))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.vel_x = 0
    self.speed = 30
    self.friction = 3.5
    self.rect.center = (420,360)
    self.delta = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000.00

def update(self):


    self.getX = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]-100 # get the X position of mouse
    self.rect.x +=self.vel_x
    ##i think the problem is in here 
    self.vel_x = self.vel_x*(1-min(self.delta*self.friction,1))


    #print "the GetX is ", self.getX
    #print "the Rect.x is ", self.rect.x
    if self.getX > self.rect.x:
        self.vel_x+= self.speed*self.delta
    else:
        self.vel_x-= self.speed*self.delta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your velocity step size. `self.speed*self.delta` is bigger than 1 pixel, which is the space that the mouse cursor consumes. Try checking for the distance between your player and the cursor. If that distance is less than a certain resolution don't update the position of the sprite.

```
resolution = 5 # pixels
if abs(self.getX - self.rect.x) > resolution:
    if self.getX > self.rect.x:
        self.vel_x+= self.speed*self.delta
    else:
        self.vel_x-= self.speed*self.delta

else:
    self.vel_x = 0
```